# Post on facebook without app

Tags: facebook

I am new to facebook API. Have created an APP which post on facebook
Now I have a situation where I have to post on a facebook page without creating any 'facebook  APP'. Is this possible with any facebook API?
what should be the simplest way?
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

No, you always need an App to post something. You need a Page Access Token, and you can only get one by authorizing a user and accessing `/me/accounts`.

If you need some links about Access Tokens, there you go:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Comment: Thanks for the information, please let me know if App Icon is a necessary field? Is there an alternative for this?

Comment: that´s a different question, but normally you only need it if you want to send some specific permission into review. you don´t need to worry about that if you only create an app for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. We only need to post on a page via APP. What will be the minimum setup? (as we need to repeat it for many websites)

Comment: that would be exactly as i answered > you need a page access token. i will include some links in my answer.